# wordpressの最大アップロードサイズ変更について質問です。

Tags: php, wordpress

現在２Mが最大となっておりまして、コレをもう少し大きくしたいです。
ウェブページでいろいろと調べましたが、良くわかりません。。。
この間あったイベントのちょっとした動画をアップロードしたいので、今から勉強すると時間がかかりすぎるため、ご質問をさせていただき、ご教授を願いました。
よろしくお願いいたします。

さて。

私の状況を説明いたします。

・現在、私のPCの環境ですが、ローカルサーバー（xamppなど）は使っておらず、htmlなどはdreamweaverで作っております。
・レンタルサーバー（共有サーバー）は「お名前.com」を使っておりまして、そこのドメインで私のウェブページをアップしております。
また、そのアップロードしているリモートサイトに、「wp」というフォルダーがありまして、そこがwordpressのルートディレクトリになっているかと思います。

ウェブで調べますと、「php.ini」を書き換える必要があるとあります。
私がわからないと思っているところは、そのphp.iniが見当たらないというところです。
なので、dreamweaverでphpファイルを開いて、そこにmax_upload_size=20Mなどと書いてアップロードしてみましたが、何も変わりません。
私の書き方がまずいのは解っておりますが、何を開いて、どのように拡張子を書いていいのか、そして、どうやってアップするのか、がわからず、途方にくれています。

私の環境で、wordpressの最大アップロードサイズを変更するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

追加で状況を報告させていただきます。

[image: １．こちらは保存用のディスク（E）に保存してある、ウェブページのフォルダーの様子です。]

[image: ２．dreamweaverでアップロードされているファイルの様子です。「php.ini」というテキストファイル（？）でしょうか、があります]

[image: ３．[dreamweaverから「ファイル→開く」とした様子です。その中には、先ほどのphp.iniのファイルがありません。]

[image: ４．php.iniとタイトルをつけたファイルは写真のように書いております。完全に間違えている感は解ってはいるのですが・・・・どうしたらいいのか。]

教えてくださったように進めたいのですが、そのphp.iniのファイルの作り方すらわかりません。。
申し訳ございませんが、教えてください

・私が考えているホームディレクトリとは
[image: ５．私が考えているディレクトリはこのように考えております。間違っているでしょうか？]

[image: ６．DWを立ち上げまして、真ん中の列にある「php」で新規ファイルを開きます。]

[image: ７．するとこの新規ページが開きます。]

[image: ８．教えていただいたコードを解らないのでヘッダーとボディの両方に書き込みました]

[image: 9.それをルートディレクトリ（ここではwpフォルダ）に「php.ini」という名前で保存します]

[image: 10・保存後、php.iniのページを一端消して、再度「ファイル」→「開く」でファイルを開こうとしますが、保存したはずのphp.iniがでません。。]

Comment: 追記しました。またPHPやサーバについてもう少し知識を広げるとよろしいかもしれません。以下のことは検索すると比較的すぐヒットすると思いますので……

Comment: 広げたいと考えておりますが、いかんせん、今回は急ぎなので。。。申し訳ないですが、皆様よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: ホームディレクトリと言うのが何処を指しているか？と言う認識は大丈夫でしょうか？設置する場所が間違っていると動作しません。また、記載されている内容に`php.ini`と言った記載がみられますが必要ないかと思います4行だけ記述しましょう。

Comment: １．こちらは保存用のディスク（E）に保存してある、ウェブページのフォルダーの様子です。
２．dreamweaverでアップロードされているファイルの様子です。「php.ini」というテキストファイル（？）でしょうか、があります

DWから「ファイル→開く」とした様子です。その中には、先ほどのphp.iniのファイルがありません。

４．php.iniとタイトルをつけたファイルは写真のように書いております。完全に間違えている感は解ってはいるのですが・・・・どうしたらいいのか。

教えてくださったように進めたいのですが、そのphp.iniのファイルの作り方すらわかりません。。

５．私が考えているディレクトリはこのように考えております。間違っているでしょうか？

６．DWを立ち上げまして、真ん中の列にある「php」で新規ファイルを開きます。
７．するとこの新規ページが開きます。

８．教えていただいたコードを解らないのでヘッダーとボディの両方に書き込みました

9.それをルートディレクトリ（ここではwpフォルダ）に「php.ini」という名前で保存します

10・保存後、php.iniのページを一端消して、再度「ファイル」→「開く」でファイルを開こうとしますが、保存したはずのphp.iniがでません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php.iniはレンタルサーバでは既に置いてあるところもあれば、
自分で設置する必要がある場所もあります。
下記を見ている限りだと自分で設置するようですね。
自身で`php.ini`を作成し、ホームディレクトリ直下に置きましょう
`php.ini`の中身は

```
;確保するメモリ量の最大値
memory_limit = 50M
;POSTリクエストを送る際のデータの最大値
post_max_size = 40M
;アップロードされるファイルの最大サイズ
upload_max_filesize = 30M
;スクリプトの実行最大時間(秒)
max_input_time = 60
```

以上が無難なところでしょう。
下記にお名前。comの`php.ini`に関する記述を記載しておきます。

> http://help.onamae.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9135/
>
> なお、「php.ini」の読み込み優先度は下記になります。 
>   1.ホームディレクトリに設置の「php.ini」
>   2.PHPスクリプトを実行するディレクトリに設置の「php.ini」 
>   3.共用サーバー共通の「php.ini」

---

**追記**
Windowsのメモ帳を使っているようですが文字コードを指定できないので指定できるフリーのテキストエディタを使用しましょう(サクラエディタなど)DWで作成するのでも良いです
テキストはコピペで構いませんが保存するファイル名をphp.iniにしましょう(拡張子をiniにすれば良いです)
またサーバに上げる際は文字コードをutf-8にし、改行コードをLFにすると良いです(Unix系のサーバのデフォルト)

---

**さらに追記**
仰っている位置に設置することで反映されるかと思います。
（※ただし上位階層に`php.ini`が無いことが前提)

**"php.ini"について**
　　`php.ini`は設定ファイルです。**PHPファイルではありません**
　　※DWで仰っているPHPとは`*.php`のPHPファイルを指します。
**INIファイルについて**
　　INIファイルは`*.ini`というファイルですが、
　　基本的に**設定値以外の項目を書き込んではいけません**
　　スクリーンショットを拝見しましたが、HTMLのタグが入りこんでいます。
　　ファイル内には回答にもある設定値の4行以外を入れてはダメです。
**開発にあたって**
　　Windowsのフォルダのスクリーンショットを見る限り拡張子が表示されない設定になっています。
　　これだとアイコンで判別するしかなくなるので**拡張子は表示する設定**にした方がいいでしょう
　　なお、フォルダオプションから設定可能です。
　　
　　また、文字コードの設定と言うのは大切です。
　　特にPHPを意識するのであれば`utf-8`にする設定は必須でしょう。
**DWについて**
　　DWを使ってINIファイルを作成するのであれば
　　`新規ドキュメント＞その他＞テキスト`にて新規ドキュメントを作成し、
　　`修正＞ページプロパティ`からドキュメントの設定を開きます。
　　`エンコーディング`を`Unicode (UTF-8)`にし、BOMのチェックボックスが外れていることを確認しOKを押し確定します。
　　設定値を入力後、ファイル名を`php.ini`に変更し、**保存先を確認して保存します。**
　　(※見ていると保存先を見失っていると思うので……)

Comment: メモ帳ではなく、dreamweaverを使って、教えていただいたコードを書いて、ファイル名をphp.iniにしましたが、ダメです。。
状況の写真をアップロードさせていただきますね。
いろいろと感謝しております

Comment: 追記しました。一度確認してください。

Comment: 大苦戦しましたが、ほんとうに！！！おかげさまで、変更できました。
出来上がったら何のことはない感じに思えましたが、それはナイスアドヴァイスのおかげです。
感謝いたします